# How to determine the type of primitive in a String representation?

Tags: java, primitive, number-formatting

I have a String representation of a primitive and my goal is to determine which primitive is it.
My function is as follows:

```
public Object getPrimitive(String primitiveAsString) {
.....
}
```

So for example I would like to return an integer in case the input is "223" but a double if the input is "223.1" or even "223.0"(!!). Moreover, I would like to separate between float and double and even between integer and "BigInteger".
I have tried a solution using NumberFormat and it didn't work for me....
Is there an elegant way to do so?
Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no elegant way about it.

Comment: Which primitive types do you need to support?

Comment: In what way can you distinguish the String representation of an integer vs the representation of BigInteger (as long as the value is between MAX_INT & MIN_INT)?

Comment: BigInteger is not a primitive. also, it does not make sense to have a method return an `object`, while the name of the method is `getPrimitive`

Comment: What exactly purpose to do it so.

Comment: Can you define what strings will look like containing `float` VS `double`?

Comment: This is not my real method of course. I'm trying to think on a way to to so. Erik, your comment about MAX_INT and MIN_INT is correct. Vijay, the method returns Object sine the String can be "true" or "abc" but in this case it is easy to identify if its a String or a boolean.

Comment: And the reason (for those of you who asked) is to initialize a Map<String, Object> that will be parsed later on by Gson.toJson(myMap) and the result will be send to client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea is just trying to return each type in try-catch.

Code: (the error-checking may be less than ideal)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(getPrimitive("123")); // Byte
    System.out.println(getPrimitive("1233")); // Short
    System.out.println(getPrimitive("1233587")); // Integer
    System.out.println(getPrimitive("123.2")); // Float
    System.out.println(getPrimitive("123.999999")); // Double
    System.out.println(getPrimitive("12399999999999999999999999")); // BigInteger
    System.out.println(getPrimitive("123.999999999999999999999999")); // BigDecimal
}

static public Object getPrimitive(String string)
{
  try { return Byte.valueOf(string);       } catch (Exception e) { };
  try { return Short.valueOf(string);      } catch (Exception e) { };
  try { return Integer.valueOf(string);    } catch (Exception e) { };
  try { return new BigInteger(string);     } catch (Exception e) { };
  try { if (string.matches(".{1,8}"))
          return Float.valueOf(string);    } catch (Exception e) { };
  try { if (string.matches(".{1,17}"))
          return Double.valueOf(string);   } catch (Exception e) { };
  try { return new BigDecimal(string);     } catch (Exception e) { };
  // more stuff ?
  return null;
}
```

The reasoning behind `.{1,8}` and `.{1,17}` is that `float` and `double` are accurate to about 7 and 16 digits each (according to some random source). `.` is a wild-card. `{x,y}` means repeated between x and y times.

**EDIT:**

Improved to differentiate `float`, `double` and `BigDecimal` with a basic regex among other things.

Comment: How will you determine the number is which belongs to BigInteger/BigDecimal, as Integer.parseInt() itself will parse it to integer correctly.

Comment: @Ankur `12399999999999999999999999` is bigger than will fit in an `Integer`, so it will fall through to `BigInteger`.

Comment: What if the number is small? Still it can belong to BigInteger

Comment: @Ankur I presume OP is looking for a greedy approach - if it's an `int`, return that, if it's `BigInteger`, return that, if it's `float`, return that, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do this very easily. It will be very tricky or almost impossible to detect if the contents of the String belongs to integer or BigInteger. You can of course distinguish between int and double/float by writing a regex to determine if it contains **'.'** and rest of the characters are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this ... this should work for BigInteger and BigDecimal as well ... Haven't tested it though.

```
public Object getPrimitive(String primitiveAsString) {
    String value = primitiveAsString;

    try {
      return Byte.valueOf(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { }

    try {
      return Short.valueOf(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { }

    try {
      return Integer.valueOf(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { }

    try {
      return Float.valueOf(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { }

    try {
      return Double.valueOf(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { }

    try {
      return Long.valueOf(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { }

    try {
      return new BigInteger(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { }

    try {
      return new BigDecimal(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { }

    if(value.length() == 1) {
      return new Character(value.charAt(0));
    }

    return null;
}
```

*EDIT*: improved the solution to cater for cases when the input is a BigInteger/BigDecimal. This solution does not use any regex.

Comment: Your order is wrong, `Byte` and `Short` will never trigger (because all `Byte`s and `Short`s are also `Integer`s . Nor will `Float` (covered by `Double`).

Comment: Try to find any test case where it will return `Double` or `BigDecimal`. `Float` will probably cover everything (even if it rounds heavily). That's why you need regex.